# Scala Futures and Promises Callback basics

Tags: scala, asynchronous, concurrency, promise, future

I'm a beginner to Scala `Futures`/`Promises`.

I'm trying to do this using `Futures` (using callbacks):

- Get the available Git Repositories.
- Get the Contributors per repository.
- Get the README file per repository.
- Finally create a GitData response per repository containing the repository URL, contributors and README.

Here is the code:

```
// Final write container to hold the result.
val promise = Promise[List[GitData]]()

val repositoriesF = Future {
  GitDriver.repositoriesOf(request.user)
}

val gitRepositories = Promise[List[GitRepository]]()

repositoriesF onSuccess {
  case repositories => {
    val contributors = Promise[List[Contributor]]()
    val contributorsF = Future(repositories.map(GitDriver.contributors))
    val readMe = Promise[List[String]]
    val readMeF = Future(repositories.map(GitDriver.readme))

    contributorsF.onSuccess {
      case contrib => contributors.success(contrib.flatten)
    }

    readMeF.onSuccess {
      case r => readMe.success(r)
    }

    val extractedContributors = contributors.future.value
    val extractedReadme = readMe.future.value
    println(extractedContributors.size)
    println(extractedReadme.size)
  }
}

Await.ready(repositoriesF, Duration.Inf)
```

The sizes of the contributors and readme are always zero.

My approach to this problem is, I can parallalize the extraction of contributors and README through `Futures` as they don't depend upon each other. All they need is just a repository object.

What am I missing here? I'm sure that there are more elegant solutions using for comprehensions, maps, dsls etc. But just curious to get to the bottom of this one! Thanks.

Comment: While the approach might be sound keep in mind that github [has limitations on the amount of requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/) you can do (not saying it's original cause of the problem)

Comment: Yes  understand that - But I'm surely well within the quota. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a few weird things. The main issue as per your problem is that you are printing the values inside this block:

```
repositoriesF onSuccess {
   case repositories => {
      ...
```

So in a sense, you are only waiting for the FIRST async computation, and have only set callbacks for the other information you need (readme and contributors). Right after setting the callbacks, those are not completed and you have no results.

The second weird thing is that you are doing `Await()` on the first future and not on the other computations. Most likely you want to wait on the entire information to be available.

The third weird thing you are doing is using too many promises. You use a Promise not when you want to get some result, but when you have to return a Future to someone else and need a way to complete that future later on, when you no longer have access to the future itself.

As for how to solve your problem, I would chain futures using for comprehensions:

```
val futureGitData = for {
  repos <- Future { GitDriver.repositoriesOf(request.user) }
  repo <- repos
  readme <- Future { GitDriver.readme(repo) } 
  contributors <- Future { GitDriver.contributors(repo) } 
} yield (repo, readme, contributors)
```

Note that this has much better parallelism, as I'm creating different futures for each repository. What you where doing, `Future(repositories.map(GitDriver.readme))` would do the map synchronously and return a single future.

*Note that I don't have Scala in this device, so that code might not be perfect, but should give you an idea.*

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you print the size of the contributors and readme the future is probably not yet completed so the `contributors.future.value` returns None.

You could try something like this:

```
val repositoriesF = Future {
  GitDriver.repositoriesOf(request.user)
}

val contributorsAndReadmeFuture = for {
  repositories <- repositoriesF
  contributors <- Future(repositories.map(GitDriver.contributors))
  readme <- Future(repositories.map(GitDriver.readme))
} yield (contributors, readme)

contributorsAndReadmeFuture onSuccess {
  case (constributors, readme) => 
    println(constributors.size)
    println(readme.size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `future.value` and `println` lines are executed before the `Futures` (the explicit with `Future(...)` and the `Promise.future` set in `onSuccess`) are completed.

The value of the `Future` is still `None`, compare with :

```
val p = Promise[Int]()
p.future.value
// Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = None
p.future.value.size
// Int = 0
```

Since you want to continue with your solution, you could do something like (without the superfluous `Promises`):

```
repositoriesF onSuccess {
  case repositories =>
    val contributorsF = Future(repositories.flatMap(GitDriver.contributors))
    val readMeF = Future(repositories.map(GitDriver.readme))

    contributorsF zip readMeF onSuccess {
      case (contrib, readme) => 
        println(contrib.size)
        println(readme.size)
    }
}
```

Comment: In this, how would I create my Response (ie GitData) - This is per repository. `case class GitData(repoUrl: String, owner: Owner, readmeContents: String, contributors: List[Contributor], programmingLanguages: List[String])`

Comment: That will be difficult since you can not return something from a call back function. I would suggest taking a better look at Daniel L's answer.